# Attribute error 'float' object has no attribute 'split' for column designated as an object

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, split, attributeerror

I am trying to split this column called "Size" in my df called spec, some sample values for this column are:

- '0.248   Dia (6.30mm)'
- '0.236   Dia x 0.394   L (6.00mm x 10.00mm)'

I am trying to parse through these values to isolate only the first portion of the values, in essence up until the first appearance of " " (the space). The column is an object type. I know that a reason for this error is usually because of NaN values so I first did:

```
spec['Size'].notnull()
```

Now with no missing values I tried the following to convert the value with are expressed in inches to millimeters:

```
#first option
spec["Size"].apply(lambda x : 0.0 if x ==" " else round(float(x.split(" ")[0])*25.4,1) )
#second option
spec["Size"].apply(lambda x : 0.0 if x =="-" else round(float(x.split(" ")[0])*25.4,1) )
#third option
spec["Size"].apply(lambda x : round(float(x.split(" ")[0])*25.4,1) )
```

Regardless though I keep getting the following error:

- AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Well, you're using split method on an explicitly float-casted variable. You can't do that, you must cast it to str, split it, and eventually cast it back to float.

Comment: I thought about that too, and when I dropped the float argument from the above code it gives this error TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'. Plus I think I need the float argument to convert the value from its original object type to a value that can be used in the subsequent multiplication operation.

Comment: I told you: you must cast the float you're trying to split into a string with str(value), split it, and then cast it back to float, not just drop the float value.